# Docker overlay network publish only some of listed ports

Tags: docker, hadoop, networking, mapping, port

I am struggling with publishing ports in docker overlay networking while setting up a hadoop cluster. I would like to publish some of ports of a hadoop master container with the following command:

```
docker run -itd --name hadoop-master --hostname hadoop-master --network hadoop \
                                    -p 8088:8088 -p 50070:50070 -p 50090:50090 \
                                    -p 8080:8080 -p 18080:18080 -p 4040:4040 \
                                    hadoop-img
```

But for some reason only the :18080 port is accessible via the browser. I am sure that all the services are running inside the docker container.

When I am inside the hadoop-master container and run:

```
curl -v localhost:18080
```

or

```
curl -v hadoop-master:18080
```

I get the same positive response (some html is displayed on the console), but when I want to do the same for port, let's say :50070 (or any other published) it is accessible only via host name i.e.:

```
curl -v hadoop-master:50070 -> displays correct html response
```

but when using localhost like:

```
curl -v localhost:50070
```

I get:

```
 About to connect() to localhost port 50070 (#0)
*   Trying ::1...
* Connection refused
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* Connection refused
* Failed connect to localhost:50070; Connection refused
* Closing connection 0
curl: (7) Failed connect to localhost:50070; Connection refused
```

So my guess is that the port :50070 is not mapped correctly inside the docker container into localhost. I have no idea why this happens. For some reason ports are published correctly while not using overlay networking. Could you please help me to solve my issue? Would be nice to have web UI's accessible.

---

my hdfs-site.xml looks like:

```
<configuration>

    <property>
        <name>dfs.replication</name>
        <value>1</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>dfs.namenode.name.dir</name>
        <value>file:///usr/local/hadoop/hdfs/namenode</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>dfs.datanode.data.dir</name>
        <value>file:///usr/local/hadoop/hdfs/datanode</value>
    </property>

    <!-- HA SETUP -->
    <property>
        <name>dfs.nameservices</name>
        <value>hadoopcluster</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>dfs.ha.namenodes.hadoopcluster</name>
        <value>nn1,nn2</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>dfs.namenode.rpc-address.hadoopcluster.nn1</name>
        <value>hadoop-master-1:8020</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>dfs.namenode.rpc-address.hadoopcluster.nn2</name>
        <value>hadoop-master-2:8020</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>dfs.namenode.http-address.hadoopcluster.nn1</name>
        <value>hadoop-master-1:50070</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>dfs.namenode.http-address.hadoopcluster.nn2</name>
        <value>hadoop-master-2:50070</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>dfs.namenode.shared.edits.dir</name>
        <value>qjournal://hadoop-jn-1:8485;hadoop-jn-2:8485;hadoop-jn-3:8485/hadoopcluster</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>dfs.client.failover.proxy.provider.hadoopcluster</name>
        <value>org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.ha.ConfiguredFailoverProxyProvider</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>dfs.ha.fencing.methods</name>
        <value>shell(/bin/true)</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>dfs.journalnode.edits.dir</name>
        <value>/opt/HDPV2/journal/node/local/data</value>
    </property>

    <!-- ZOOKEEPER SETUP -->

     <property>
        <name>dfs.ha.automatic-failover.enabled</name>
        <value>true</value>
    </property>

     <property>
        <name>ha.zookeeper.quorum</name>
        <value>zookeeper-1:2181,zookeeper-2:2181,zookeeper-3:2181</value>
    </property>

</configuration>
```

So far I have created a basic setup that runs all the services in separate containers spread across two docker hosts:

- 3 x zookeeper containers
- 3 x journal nodes containers
- 2 x master containers (resource manager, namenode, HistoryServer and DFSZKFailoverController)
- 3 x slave containers (datanode and nodemanager)

Comment: I find it hard to believe that some ports are mapped correctly and others not. It usually is all or nothing. Since it is a web application, it could be that the webserver is configured in such a way as to listen for a combination of port and hostname. When you run the curl to localhost, is it from inside the container or outside? And why do you need `localhost` when `hadoop-master` works fine?

Comment: @Mihai all the commands were run inside the docker container and I need it being mapped to the localhost, because I would like to access the web interface of hadoop from my docker deamon host. It seems that it works only if hostname inside the docker container is mapped to localhost.

Comment: Can you add hadoop-master to /etc/hosts and point to 127.0.0.1? Would that solve your issue to access the UI from the host?

Comment: @Mihai the same notification ```Connection refused...``` is displayed when I point ```hadoop-master-1``` to ```127.0.0.1```

Answer (score 0):

Your hdfs-site.xml *should not* be configured to use localhost addresses or hostname addresses. See `dfs.namenode.http-address.hadoopcluster.nnX` props

`dfs.namenode.http-address` defaults to bind to `0.0.0.0:50070`, therefore will be available outside the container once you forward it.

Also, there is `dfs.datanode.http.address=0.0.0.0:50075`, which also shouldn't be touched.

And you want to add `dfs.namenode.rpc-bind-host=0.0.0.0`

If the namenode isn't running, then that is a separate issue entirely. Spark UI will start fine without an active Namenode (port 18080). You just cannot run Spark jobs that require HDFS.

Note: NameNode, DataNode+NodeManager, ResourceManager, and Spark services should all be **separate containers** (ideally on separate machines). Otherwise, you are just building up a single-point of failure in a container and might as well use a proper VM.

Comment: I have omitted the datanodes ports (UI) deliberately while not publishing them outside. Also as mentioned, I am sure that the namenodes are running because of simply typing ```jps``` or  ```curl -v hadoop-master-1``` inside the ```hadoop-master-1``` container which confirms they are up. Submitting SparkPI.jar also succeeds.

Comment: [SparkPi doesn't read/write from HDFS](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/examples/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/examples/SparkPi.scala#L27-L40)

Comment: In this case tomorrow I will create my own spark job and try it out on real data in HDFS. However it seems to me that it is not the issue because when using docker bridge network instead of overlay one, the same configuration yielded two correctly working web interfaces of namenodes on published ports :50070 and 50069 (one for active namenode and second for standby one). The issue started occurring when I decided to use some advantages of swarm and overlay networking to combine two docker hosts (servers).

Comment: There is a TestHDFS job that is included in Spark. No need to write your own

Comment: I can't help with Swarm. I only know running Hadoop in k8s or nomad (where Spark is supported)

Comment: Basically, the issue is either with the external host firewalls, or you have configured bind addresses to only listen locally.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206320/discussion-between-supercolo-and-cricket-007).